# Gpio under linux olimex

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gpio

I am using olimex 3188 board and am trying to access gpios. When I attempt : `ls -l /sys/class/gpio` I get :

```
export 
gpiochip160
gpiochip192
gpiochip224
gpiochip256
unexport
```

`cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip160/ngpio` returns 32

`cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip160/label` returns gpio0

`cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip192/label` returns gpio1

and so on until gpio3

I have read and understood what each block consists of, but for example I want to access pin : GPIO0_B4. Where does this pin belong?

Comment: *"cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip160/ngpio returns gpio0"* -- Something's wrong.  `npio` should be a number, not text.

Comment: I am sorry 32.I am going to correct it